# Apache2 SSL Certificate/Key mismatch

Tags: ssl, apache2, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to set-up Apache to use a private key and certificate for SSL usage. The problem is that Apache somehow thinks that the key and the crt files do not match:

```
[Thu Aug 01 11:35:18 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.-----.nl' does NOT match server name!?
[Thu Aug 01 11:35:18 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(846): Configuring RSA server private key
[Thu Aug 01 11:35:18 2013] [error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Thu Aug 01 11:35:18 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

After this error i checked wether or not the key and the certificate matched using:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt | openssl md5
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key | openssl md5
```

And the results are both the same, so it seems that the key and the certificate do match!? My site configuration contains the folowing for SSL set-up:

```
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
```

The certificate is signed by a self created CA that i use for my customers. At this moment i'm hosting the HTTPS site through Java (and Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari/... all accept the certificate and key), however the performance is not as i'd like it to be, hence i'm willing to switch to Apache. However i don't understand why Apache says the certificate and the key do not match? I've googled a lot for this error and found a lot of results however none represent my situation nor provide a valid solution for my problem. The reason i use my own CA is that i have a few hundred (and counting) certificates in use for a trust based network.

edit:
The issue seems openssl related, i tested the following with the same final error:

```
..............:~$ openssl s_server -cert server.crt -key server.key
140518544565920:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140518544565920:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:831:
140518544565920:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:751:Field=n, Type=RSA
140518544565920:error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib:rsa_ameth.c:115:
Using default temp DH parameters
Using default temp ECDH parameters
error setting private key
140518544565920:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:331:
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction for what i'm doing wrong?

I retranscoded the used JKS directly used by the webserver (accepted by all browsers) to PEM certificate and private key, but still when i get the same error from openssl:

```
openssl s_server -debug -cert server.crt -key server.key
Using default temp DH parameters
Using default temp ECDH parameters
error setting private key
140157841004192:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:331:
```

How is it possible that all browsers accept the key/cert combination and openssl refuses to use them together?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658484/ssl-install-problem-key-value-mismatch-but-they-do-match

Comment: @Nick ? please explain your comment.

Comment: @kenorb I know the key and certificates match, and already tryed to put them into one file in the named order. However that does not seem to help.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ openssl s_server -cert server.crt -key server.key
140518544565920:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140518544565920:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:831:
140518544565920:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:751:Field=n, Type=RSA
140518544565920:error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib:rsa_ameth.c:115:
```

Add `-keyform`. It can be DER or PEM. You'll have to look at `server.key` to determine the form.

If `server.key` has `--- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY ---` (or similar), its PEM. If its not PEM encoded, then try DER.

Also, `server.key` might be encrypted. You might have to re-save the key without a passphrase.

Answer (score 4):

What does your virtual hosts file look like?
Without seeing that file it's hard to tell why you are getting the warning. However, the warning is most likely coming from your virtual hosts file having a different server name than what the SSL cert has been set up for.
Check your virtual hosts file and change

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

or even

```
<VirtualHost yoursevername:443>
```

Comment: The issue is related to open_ssh since it also occurs in ope_ssl without apache. the host name is therefore unrelated. The virtual hosts file is set up as <VirtualHost domain:443>

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you have in your `<VirtualHost ...:443>` line, I think the problem is indicated by the line in your error log:

```
[warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.-----.nl' does NOT match server name!?
```

What is the `ServerName` from your VirtualHost and does it match the CN of your certificate, i.e. the last entry in the "Subject:" line of the output from `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <certfile>`

Also, did you try noloader's suggestion?