# "key values mismatch" when using context.use_certificate_chain_file

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, gnutls

When using `context.use_certificate_chain_file` I get a key error (openssl.Context Python). The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/public_html/application.py", line 363, in <module>
    context.use_privatekey_file('/etc/ssl/private/' + HOSTNAME + '.key')
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_check_private_key', 'key values mismatch')]
```

It saying a key values mismatch, but I wouldn't think the chain would affect that.

If I comment the context.use_certificate_chain_file line, it works perfectly (but gives an ssl verification error in the browser).

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
context = openssl.Context(openssl.SSLv23_METHOD)
context.set_options(openssl.OP_NO_SSLv2)
context.set_options(openssl.OP_NO_SSLv3)
context.use_certificate_file('/etc/ssl/certs/' + HOSTNAME + '.crt')
context.use_certificate_chain_file('/etc/ssl/certs/' + HOSTNAME + '.cabundle')
context.use_privatekey_file('/etc/ssl/private/' + HOSTNAME + '.key')
context.set_cipher_list(':'.join(supported_ciphers))
```

Any ideas why its giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why its giving the error?

The error is propagated up from OpenSSL. Its error 0x0B080074:

```
$ openssl errstr 0x0B080074
error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

Based on [SSL install problem - “key value mismatch” (but they do match?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4658484), you have one of two problems.

First, the private key does not match the public key in the certificate. Second, your `certificate_chain_file` is missing the intermediate certificates required to build a valid path from the server's certificate to a root. Here, the root would be the CA that signed your certificate.

So your fix is to either (1) ensure the public/private key pair is in fact a pair, or (2) include the necessary intermediate certificates in the chain file.

Without knowing the private key (`'/etc/ssl/private/' + HOSTNAME + '.key'`), the server certificate (`'/etc/ssl/certs/' + HOSTNAME + '.crt'`) or the contents of the chain file (`'/etc/ssl/certs/' + HOSTNAME + '.cabundle'`), we really can't give you more details on how to fix it.

---

You can provide us with the server's certificate with:

```
cat '/etc/ssl/certs/' + HOSTNAME + '.crt' | openssl x509 -text -noout
```

You can provide us with the chain file by just cat'ing. It will be 3 or 4 PEM encoded certificates concatenated together:

```
cat `'/etc/ssl/certs/' + HOSTNAME + '.cabundle'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working now, the chain had to be appended to the crt.