# SSL handshake failing with "sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40"

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, handshake

I have a .pfx file, which can perfectly connect to the remote server when used on a windows client. I want to now connect to server using a linux client.

Problem 1) I used following openssl commands to extract public cert and private key from the pfx file,

```
openssl pkcs12 -in Name.pfx -nocerts -out priv.pem -nodes
openssl pkcs12 -in Name.pfx -nokeys -out pub.pem
```

But when I ran following two commands to verify md5 of both files, I found both of them different.

```
openssl rsa -noout -text -in priv.pem | openssl md5
openssl x509 -noout -text -in pub.pem | openssl md5
```

Problem 2) I instead used following command to extract single pem file from pfx that has both cert and key.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in Name.pfx -out bundle.pem
```

Using this pem file I tried connecting to the remote server, with following command :

```
openssl s_client -servername 1.2.3.4 -connect 1.2.3.4:1234 -CAfile bundle.pem -state -tls1_2
```

This gives following output on terminal

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=0 O = "My Name", CN = Name - Local
verify return:1
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:failed in SSLv3 read finished A
140250807310240:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1275:SSL alert number 40
140250807310240:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/O=My Name /CN=Name - Local
   i:/O=My Name /CN=Name - Local
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<random string of certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/O=My Name /CN=Name - Local
issuer=/O=My Name /CN=Name - Local
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, secp521r1, 521 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1332 bytes and written 206 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: <some string>
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: <some string>
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1495217834
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I cant figure out why is handshake failing. Stuck for 3 days, where exactly does problem lie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But when I ran following two commands to verify md5 of both files, I found both of them different.
>
> ```
> openssl rsa -noout -text -in priv.pem | openssl md5
> openssl x509 -noout -text -in pub.pem | openssl md5
> ```

The first command shows textual information about the private key. The second textual information about the certificate which contains the public key. Of course these information are different.

> Using this pem file I tried connecting to the remote server, with following command :
>
> ```
> openssl s_client -servername 1.2.3.4 -connect 1.2.3.4:1234 -CAfile bundle.pem -state -tls1_2
> ```

This uses the certificate as a trusted CA (`-CAfile`). This is probably not what you want. Instead you want to use the certificate as a client certificate. This should be done [as documented](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/s_client.html) by using the options  `-cert` and `-key`, i.e. `-cert bundle.pem -key bundle.pem` in your case.

Apart from that `-servername` should be a hostname and not an IP address. If you don't have a hostname skip this option.

> ```
> SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
> ...
> SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A
> ...
> SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
> ```

Since you don't specify the client certificate properly an empty client certificate will be send. But the server expects a valid client certificate and thus report a failed handshake within an SSL alert back to the client.

Comment: But there are articles ( like https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4064 ) which say that md5 output of those two files should be same. Also, I removed CAfile flag and instead using cert & key flags as you suggested. The terminal asks for the passphrase and then it fails again saying "error setting private key
140495240427424:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:331:"

Comment: @AbhayJain: You are using the option `-text`. In the article you reference the option `-modulus` is used instead. With the last option the result should be the same, with the first option not.

Comment: @AbhayJain: and as for your other problem see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658484/ssl-install-problem-key-value-mismatch-but-they-do-match

Comment: I replaced -text with -modulus but they still mismatch. Am I using wrong command to extract from pfx?

Comment: @AbhayJain: my guess is that your pfx file contains multiple certificates, i.e. leaf certificate and chain certificates. In this case `openssl x509` will take the first exported one which might be the wrong one (i.e. the chain certificate) and thus not match the key. And because of this wrong order you get also the later problems as described in the question I've linked to. Try to use `-clcerts` to export the leaf certificate only.

Comment: I had the same issue and adding the client certificate has solved it. But don't understand why it is a must to provide it, it should be optional, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Badr: It  is fully up to the server if it a) requests a client certificate in the first place and b) accepts that the client does not send any even if requested. If the server requires a client certificate then providing it is not optional.