# Failed to start apache after adding SSL

Tags: ssl, debian, apache2

I have added ssl cert to my web server.
There is debian 9 with apache2 installed.

This is 000-default.cnf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ServerName www.xxx.xx

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/xs/nazwa.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/xs/nazwa.key

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Cert files are ok. How to repair it?
After starting apache there appears an error:

`Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.` I know that this is because of SSL.

Comment: is mod-ssl installed/enabled ?

Comment: yes its enabled. I found error "AH02565: Certificate and private key www.xxx.xxx.pl:443:0 from /etc/ssl/lss/nazwa.crt and /etc/ssl/lss/nazwa.key do not match
" but files are ok..

Comment: have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658484/ssl-install-problem-key-value-mismatch-but-they-do-match)